# Python: Pair bluetooth speaker

Tags: python, bluetooth, pybluez

**Problem:**
I have a Logitech BT Adapter connected to a bunch of speakers at home. I have its address stored on my laptop and I want to use python to attempt to pair with it.

**What I have tried:**
I have tried using both RFCOMM and L2CAP using the examples from [this](https://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/x232.html) website.

**Error Messages:**
When I tried to connect using RFCOMM on port `0`:

`Traceback (most re[...]bluetooth.btcommon.BluetoothError: (112, 'Host is down')`

When I tried to connect using L2CAP on port `0x1001`:

`Traceback (most re[...]bluetooth.btcommon.BluetoothError: (111, 'Connection Refused')`

**Things I also have questions about:**

- Is there a specific port I should be using when trying to connect to my speaker?
- Is there a way in which I can simply 'tell' my laptop, through python, to connect to the speaker?